# Pillow has already installed, but appears ImportError - Python3.5 Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I used `sudo pip3` to install `Pillow` in Python 3.5 (without `sudo` it will prompt `PermissonError`) and it said

> Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

But when I tried to use it in the Program. It shows:

```
File "./level7.py", line 4, in <module>
  from Pillow import Image
ImportError: No module named 'Pillow'
```

My first few lines in my program are:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Pillow import Image
```

Besides, I found that in `/home/-uname/.local/lib` file, there is a `Python2.7` file, but no Python3.5.

What's the relation between `/usr/local` and `/home/-uname/.local`? And how to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes , I use `sudo` with `pip3`.

Comment: If you look at the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/handbook/tutorial.html) for Pillow, you will see how you are actually supposed to import it: `from PIL import Image`

Comment: @idjaw, please turn your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted as the correct answer to this question

Comment: As a side note, @DaChen, please look into using virtual environments

    `python3 -m venv venv`
    `source venv/bin/activate`
    `pip install Pillow`
    `python`
    `from PIL import Image` https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: @DaChen I would take the advice that just Seth Difley suggested. Virtual Environments keep your environment clean and contained. Here is the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

Comment: @SethDifley I'll try it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @DaChen I asked because it looked like you were using `sudo` with `pip3` but that is bad practice in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of the [documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/handbook/tutorial.html) for Pillow, you are actually supposed to import it as:

```
from PIL import Image
```